# Post Form with file upload to server, only file name showing in request?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I am using Node.js for server and trying to upload file to server through form. I have checked other posts and most of them suggest the following approach, but I print the full *req* and cannot find the field in most suggested approaches:

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/imageupload">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/jpeg, image/png"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" id="search" />
</form>
```

In server:

```
app.post('/imageupload', function (req, res){
    //var imgPath = req.files.image;
    console.log(req);
});
```

Here is what I found in the req that is different from what other posts suggest:

```
 headers: 
  { host: 'localhost:8081',
 connection: 'keep-alive',
 'content-length': '33',
 'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
 accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 origin: 'http://localhost:8081',
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36',
 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 dnt: '1',
 referer: 'http://localhost:8081/',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2',
 cookie: 'JSESSIONID=89875bd29370ecf4ae585822f40c; treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:updateCenterPlugIN; connect.sid=s%3AJJfmZcGvlE388fwSVSNeoQ6Y0hV55Wur.VQdPuxk0W%2BHHt2zmKLlBxqdUFFXJumtGOOcQVcoeJSI' },

body: { file: 'sampleimg.jpg', search: 'Search' },
```

I cannot find any field indicating files, and accessing it result in error in server:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
```

So I am not sure what went wrong. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: I dont know know if you are using express or not but if you are multer, https://github.com/expressjs/multer,  is great for file uploads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form to

```
<form method="POST" action="/imageupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Add `enctype`. As the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) says it is required when we do a file upload.

`body-parser` only handles JSON. To handle `multipart` I suggest you to use [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy). It handles multipart form data.

Comment: It does not change much. content type change to 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryXpN5AELGKCFOU0Su',

and body is {}. And accessing req.files.image still gives same error

Comment: @AmyWang R u using bodyparser to handle json?

Comment: @AmyWang. Thats the problem. See the updated answer. You can also use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) but I prefer this one.